# Table Border in HTML/CSS

Tags: html, html-table, border

I am creating a table in HTML and trying to assign the cells a border. Here is how it appears.

[image]

See that weird border in 2nd row, last cell. That's the problem I am having.

```
<table class="info">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>Some text</td>
            <td>Some text</td>
            <td>Some text</td>
            <td>Some text</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><span>0</span></td>
            <td><span>0</span></td>
            <td><span>0</span></td>
            <td><span>0</span></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Some text</td>
            <td>Some text</td>
            <td>Some text</td>
            <td>Some text</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><span>0</span></td>
            <td><span>0</span></td>
            <td><span>0</span></td>
            <td><span>0</span></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Some text</td>
            <td>Some text</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><span>0</span></td>
            <td><span>0</span></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Here's my css....

```
table.info {
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
}

table.info td {
    background: #fff;
    border: 2px solid #ccc;
    text-align: center;
}
```

What am I doing wrong over here?

UPDATE - I checked the css being inherited and I found this...

```
table {
  border-collapse:collapse;
  border-spacing:0;
}
```

Comment: What browser? It's working on my FF3.6.

Comment: @bobby - mine is 3.6 as well. 3.6.12 to be precise

Comment: @bobby - its working on Chrome

Comment: @ShiVik: Same FF version here...that's odd. Maybe further css settings are interfering with it?

Comment: @Bobby - there were some css settings I found. Could they be the reason?

Comment: @ShiVik: Ah, it's the `border-collapse` setting which screws it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this will help:

(HTML)

```
<table class="info">
  <tbody>
      <tr>
          <td>Some text</td>
          <td>Some text</td>
          <td>Some text</td>
          <td>Some text</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
          <td><span>0</span></td>
          <td><span>0</span></td>
          <td><span>0</span></td>
          <td><span>0</span></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
          <td>Some text</td>
          <td>Some text</td>
          <td>Some text</td>
          <td>Some text</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
          <td><span>0</span></td>
          <td><span>0</span></td>
          <td><span>0</span></td>
          <td><span>0</span></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
          <td>Some text</td>
          <td>Some text</td>
          <td colspan="2" class="empty">&nbsp;</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
          <td><span>0</span></td>
          <td><span>0</span></td>
          <td colspan="2" class="empty">&nbsp;</td>
      </tr>
  </tbody>
```

(CSS)

```
table.info {
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
}

table.info td {
    background: #fff;
    border: 2px solid #ccc;
    text-align: center;
}

table.info .empty {
  border:none;
}
```

Comment: Thanks Ivan. This works perfectly for me - although breaks the notion of "table representing tabular data", but doesn't require me to change the code already written. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 7):

Your HTML is not correct. Either you must have equal no. of TDs in your each row or you can match markup by using rowspan/colspan.

Comment: hmmmm. Ok will try that. not the answer I was looking for though - doesn't solve problem, instead changes my specification, but if it works - what the heck. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

for the last 2 rows make a cell with colspan=2..something like this:

```
<tr>
      <td><span>0</span></td>
      <td><span>0</span></td>
      <td colspan="2"></td>
  </tr>
```

Answer (score 1):

ok i have tested it .. and it's not working on firefox.. but chrome and ie allow you to use tables with different numbers of columns on each row... as @chinmayee said, its not correct to do that, cause tables are only used to represent tabular data.. i'd sugest you to change your html and use divs with float to obtain the effect that you want..

good luck